# Sqlalchemy - executing raw sql queries

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy in a flask application that connects to multiple databases, using binds as shown [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/). I want to execute a raw sql query on one of the non-primary databases.

I'm trying to use [session.execute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute), as shown here but it executes for the primary db. The API docs state that you can use a parameter: "bind – Optional Engine to be used as the bind". How do I access and specify the bind for the non-primary db and call session.execute to execute a query for that db?

Alternately, is there any other way to go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
from flask import current_app
db.get_engine(current_app, bind='<your_bind>').execute('<your raw sql>')
```