# Python flask: Unable to query a MySQL table ,convert MySQL language to Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to migrate my currently working rest APIs from backand.com to pythonanywhere that is created by flask framework.

**Backand.com MySQL**

```
SELECT `Trade`  AS trade, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `KLSE`
GROUP BY `Trade`
```

**Flask_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/KLSEstats', methods=['GET'])
def KLSEstats(Trade):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='vinuk.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='user',passwd='xxx',db='vinusdb$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    curs = db.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT Trade ,COUNT(*) FROM KLSE GROUP BY Trade")
        e = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Trade': e})
```

Unfortunately, it returns 500 internal server error
My full json table is in this [link](http://vinus.pythonanywhere.com/KLSE)

```
curs.execute("SELECT Trade FROM KLSE")
```

Trying above command also return 500 error. I know the command I use is not correct.
I wanted to count the total of the BUY,SeLL,HOLD in the MySQL database table. I know there are some differences using mySQLdb module but unable to find more example so that I can convert mySQL language to Python.

Comment: 500 internal server error doesn't say anything. Do python(3) __init__.py or whatever your filename is and post the actual error

Comment: run flask_app.py actually has no error

Comment: What I usually do is turn off apache and use the debugging server. Insert multiple print statements to locate where the error occurred and see If I can fix it.

Comment: turn off apache. Where to turn off in pythonanywhere?

Comment: @vindex i believe Bobby means turn off apache locally on your development machine and use flask inbuilt server

Comment: @danidee, unfortunately, I use pythonanywhere, which is cloud and not a local machine

Comment: @vindex I mean stop using any production server. Instead, use the build in development server to see console outputs

Comment: @vindex optimally you should run the program in your local environment with the flask debug server and remove the offending code line from the `try` statement to be able to see what the actual error is. Try if by chance this answer helps you as it seems that what you are trying to do is execute raw SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664898/sqlalchemy-executing-raw-sql-queries/39665182#39665182

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- check out the error log (linked from the "Web" tab).  That will have the details of any errors Flask is generating.