# executing a raw sql query from sqlalchemy on postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a raw sql query which is:

```
select distinct(user_id) from details_table where event_id in (29,10) and user_id in (7,11,24,45) and epoch_timestamp >= 1433116800 and epoch_timestamp <= 1506816000;
```

which in `psql` returns:

```
 user_id 
---------
       7
      24
(2 rows)
```

Now when i run this raw sql query via sqlalchemy I'm getting a `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy` object in response and not the result as above. The code i'm using right now is as follows:

```
from flask import current_app
sql_query = text(select distinct(user_id) from details_table where event_id in (29,10) and user_id in (7,24) and epoch_timestamp >= 1433116800 and epoch_timestamp <= 1506816000;)

filtering_users = db.get_engine(current_app, bind='<my_binding>')\
                    .execute(sql_query)
print(type(filtering_users))
# <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy'>
print(filtering_users)
# <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x7fde74469550>
```

I used the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664898/sqlalchemy-executing-raw-sql-queries) but unlike the solution there I'm getting a ResultProxy object.

What am I doing wrong here? My end goal is to get the list of users returned from executing the raw sql-query, stored into a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained is the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute), the `.execute()` method returns only a proxy on which you'll have to iterate (or apply any aggregation method) to view the actual result of the query. Apparently, in your case, what you want is the `.fetchall()` [method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=fetchall#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.fetchall).

If you try something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('/path/to/your/db...')
connection = engine.connect()

my_query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'
results = connection.execute(my_query).fetchall()
```

the `results` variable will be a `list` of all the items that the query fetches.

Hope this helps!